# Best way to store an ordered list of objects that are of different types in Java?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, collections, java-8

I have several classes that are used to create objects. These objects each have code that must be run that depends on the order of insertion.

They need to be stored in order - and recalled in the order they were stored.

1. Object A
2. Object B
3. Object A
4. Object A
5. Object C
6. Object D

I'm not sure if the proper way of handling this in Java is a generic list and checking typing at runtime.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

I've also thought about storing each object type in their own typed list with a parent object reading from the lists in the proper order. However, this seems more complex than just dealing with checking object types at runtime.

What is the proper "Java" way to handle this?

Comment: Do these objects implement a common interface? Can they? Are you sure?

Comment: To make all the classes implement a common interface or extend a common superclass, defining the common `call()` method. Then to create a List<ThatInterface>, to iterate over it, and to call `.call()` on each of them. That's the whole principle of polymorphism.

Comment: @JBNizet What would this `call` method do, what behavior?

Comment: It would do what the OP means by "They need to be [...] recalled in the order they were stored".

Comment: @JBNizet How would the interface manage this functionality? Can you give a rough outline of your logic here?

Comment: The interface doesn't manage anything. All classes implement the interface, and when you call thatInterface.call(), you actually call A.call() if thatInterface is an instance of A, or B.call if thatInterface is an instance of B. Really, it's the basic principle of interfaces and polymorphism. Your text book **must** cover that. The Java tutorial does: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: @JBNizet I believe you are misunderstanding the issue. These classes aren't related. They share no common ancestor. I must simply create and remember what order they were added to a collection of some sort. This is an architecture issue - but one I cannot resolve. I could implement a common interface - but I see how that could get the order in any meaningful way that offers advantages besides a basic list of untyped objects.

Can you clarify your suggested implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the objects do not share a common ancestor:

> These classes aren't related. They share no common ancestor.

Then what you can do is to create another class that acts as a wrapper for:

1. An object of type `T`.
2. A `Consumer<T>` object to act as a reference to the code that needs to be invoked.

For example:

```
    class Invocable<T> {
        private final T target;
        private final Consumer<T> invocation;
        
        public Invocable(T target, Consumer<T> invocation) {
            this.target = target;
            this.invocation = invocation;
        }
        
        public void runInvocation() {
            invocation.accept(target);
        }
    }
```

Then create another class that manages a `List<Invocable>` like the following:

```
class RunnableList {
    
    private List<Invocable<?>> invocables = new ArrayList<Invocable<?>>();
    
    public <T> void add(T target, Consumer<T> invocation) {
        invocables.add(new Invocable<T>(target, invocation));
    }
    
    public void run() {
        invocables.forEach(Invocable::runInvocation);
    }
}
```

And that's it! Just add ANY object to the `RunnableList` using the `add(T target, Consumer<T> invocation)` method and when you are done adding all your objects (with a reference to the respective code to be invoked) just invoke `run` on the `RunnableList`.

The following is a full working example of this, try it out to get the idea:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class RunnableList {
    
    private List<Invocable<?>> invocables = new ArrayList<Invocable<?>>();
    
    public <T> void add(T target, Consumer<T> invocation) {
        invocables.add(new Invocable<T>(target, invocation));
    }
    
    public void run() {
        invocables.forEach(Invocable::runInvocation);
    }

    static class Invocable<T> {
        private final T target;
        private final Consumer<T> invocation;
        
        public Invocable(T target, Consumer<T> invocation) {
            this.target = target;
            this.invocation = invocation;
        }
        
        public void runInvocation() {
            invocation.accept(target);
        }
    }
    
    // TEST
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnableList runnableList = new RunnableList();
        runnableList.add(new ClassA(), o -> o.run1("hello from A1"));
        runnableList.add(new ClassB(), o -> o.run1("hello from B1"));
        runnableList.add(new ClassC(), o -> o.run1("hello from C1"));

        runnableList.add(new ClassA(), ClassA::run2);
        runnableList.add(new ClassB(), ClassB::run2);
        runnableList.add(new ClassC(), ClassC::run2);
        runnableList.run();
    }
    
    static class ClassA {
        public void run1(String msg) {
            System.out.println("A.run1: " + msg);
        }
        public void run2() { System.out.println("A.run2"); }
    }
    static class ClassB {
        public void run1(String msg) {
            System.out.println("B.run1: " + msg);
        }
        public void run2() { System.out.println("B.run2"); }
    }
    static class ClassC {
        public void run1(String msg) {
            System.out.println("C.run1: " + msg);
        }
        public void run2() { System.out.println("C.run2"); }
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a59121698)

Hope this helps.